# servlet + video streaming + ClientAbortException

Tags: java, servlets, streaming

I am facing this issue with the servlet when i am trying to stream video file from the server.
The code to server the file

```
    if (contentType == null) {
        contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    }

    response.reset();
    response.setBufferSize(ServerConfiguration.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    response.setContentType(contentType);
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public") ;


     BufferedInputStream input = null;
     BufferedOutputStream output = null;

        try {
            // Open streams.
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), ServerConfiguration.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), ServerConfiguration.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

            // Write file contents to response.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[ServerConfiguration.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log(e);
        }
            finally {
            // Gently close streams.
            close(output);
            close(input);
        }
```

I have set the **content-disposition to 'inline'** and when i debug i can see the request coming to the server in an infinite loop and each time it throws this error:

```
ClientAbortException:  java.io.IOException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:369)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:327)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:392)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:381)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:93)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at com.venividi.ResourceManager.UploadFileManager.getMediaFiles(UploadFileManager.java:118)
at com.venividi.Servlet.VenividiServlet.doGet(VenividiServlet.java:182)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.venividi.Servlet.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:29)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:306)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:322)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1732)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.io.IOException
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:208)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:238)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:84)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:190)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:533)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:364)
... 28 more
```

If i change the **content disposition type to attachment** - i am able to download the file and play the file from localsytem (which means the data is correct) but am not able to play this video file(thru the url)using VLC player (network stream option) or my custom iphone media player.

I want to do something like the server - http://www.yo-yo.org/mp4/yu.mp4 .. i can play this file by giving the URL to VLC or my Iphone app  .. website for the file (http://www.yo-yo.org/mp4/) ..

The response header of the yo-yo mp4 file is

*Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:7846115
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 15 Aug 2011 18:01:12 GMT
ETag:"32a000f-77b8e3-3bd314df3c340"
Keep-Alive:timeout=2
Last-Modified:Fri, 09 May 2003 01:39:49 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.8 (Fedora)*

while the response header of my server is

*Cache-Control:public
Content-Disposition:inline; filename="3648ef48-71bf-4393-9c0e-89fda68a683c.mp4"
Content-Length:7846115
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Mon, 15 Aug 2011 18:10:07 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1*

Please provide some suggestions . I will really appreciate any help

Regards
surya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution to the above issue. The chrome sends byte-range requests and the server should handle such requests, rather than writing the complete file in a single request.

This link is helpful: [Servlet Supporting Resume](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html)

Comment: Hi surya, Can you post example code, because i'm also have same issue in video streaming. BalusC link have example to handle text, image and Zip files only. But i want to handle video files. Can you please share some example code and way to write the code to handle video files in servlet...

Comment: BalusC code worked for me for audio/video files. On all browsers/devices. You can optimize the code by using networked i/o library of Java but the logic in the code works